# Programming an ATtiny84

Tags: macos, usb, avr, atmel

I am designing a mobile device around an [Attiny84 microcontroller](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11232) and when I have looked up ways of programming it and making it run, I found that I would need a JTAG progammer. Could the Attiny84 be programmed by USB with something else like a 6 pin header? What other ways can the Attiny84 be programmed?

P.S. No arduino and I am using snow leopard on my mac

Answer (score 1):

The ATTiny84 can be programmed over SPI. See section 19.5 (page 163) of [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8006.pdf) for details.

To do this, you will need an AVR programmer (**not** a JTAG programmer; that's something quite different). One inexpensive option is the [USBtinyISP](http://www.adafruit.com/products/46).

Comment: Can I write my program onto an SD card and have the Attiny84 run off of that (Im trying to make a small device that I use away from the computer)

Comment: No. AVR processors can only execute code from internal program memory.

Comment: Well, actually, I think you could have a bootloader load the data off SD card and then run that. Looks like ATTiny84 can have a bootloader, so it is possible *in theory*, though probably not recommended in practice.

Comment: Honestly, probably not. The program flash on the '84 is pretty damn small (8 KB); by the time you got done writing an SD bootloader, I'm not sure you'd have enough space left for the program it loaded. :)